# Understanding .config in localStorage example

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angular.js, I have built a few demo applications so as to understand angular.js. I came across the following demo **[HERE](http://file:///C:/Users/Silambu/Desktop/angular-localStorage/demo/demo.html)**, it's on localStorage, now when I checked the [demo-app.js](http://gregpike.net/demos/angular-local-storage/demo/demo-app.js) file, I see the following code right at the beginning:

```
angular.module('demoModule', ['LocalStorageModule'])
.config(['localStorageServiceProvider', function(localStorageServiceProvider){
  localStorageServiceProvider.setPrefix('demoPrefix');
  // localStorageServiceProvider.setStorageCookieDomain('example.com');
  // localStorageServiceProvider.setStorageType('sessionStorage');
}])
```

I fail to understand what impact this piece of code has on the application as a whole, I have seen **[THIS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZtqzeYooMw4)** tutorial too , but I still don't understand what exactly that `config` part is doing ? Can somebody explain ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A provider is a component that is used by angular to create the unique instance of a service.

It's useful because sometimes, before the service is created and used for the first time, it needs to be configured.

That's what the `config()` function is for. A function passed to `config()` can be injected with service providers, and is executed by Angular at the very beginning, before the application actually starts.

In this case, I guess it's used to specify that every key stored in local storage by the localStorageService is prefixed with `'demoPrefix'`. That can be useful to prevent clashes with other libraries storing keys in localStorage. The documentation of `localStorageServiceProvider` should explain it.

Comment: i believe `LocalStorageModule` is the directive ,  but what is `localStorageServiceProvider` , i mean whats the technical term for it ?

Comment: No, as its name indicates, LocalStorageModule is a module. As my answer says, and as its name indicates, `localStorageServiceProvider` is the **provider** of the service `localStorageService`. provider is the technical term.

Comment: when you say provider .. do you mean the provider that i see here -- http://blog.xebia.com/2013/09/01/differences-between-providers-in-angularjs/   .... scroll to the section provider :)

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean